# Is it possible to only populate certain fields MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using the following model schema:

```
var AppointmentSchema = new Schema({
    appointment_date: {type: Date},
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    updated: {type: Date},
    client: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }], 
    staff_id: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }], 
    cost:{
        type: Number
    }, 
    jobDone:{
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false
    },  
    cancelled:{
        type: Boolean, 
        default: false
    }
});
```

Which clearly references the User model.

When I query I want to populate the client and staff data, but without some of the fields that they hold within that model.

So if the Users model is:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your first name']
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        default: '',
        validate: [validateLocalStrategyProperty, 'Please fill in your last name']
    },
    displayName: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    }
});
```

I would only want to populate with firstName and email (and omit the rest) is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

To return a few specific fields returned for the **[populated](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)** documents, you need to pass the usual [field name syntax](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) as the second argument to the populate method:

```
Appointment 
.findOne({ cancelled: true })
.populate('client', 'firstName displayName') // only return the User's firstName and displayName
.exec(function (err, appointment) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);

    console.log('The client name is %s', appointment.client.firstName);
    // prints "The client name is Aaron"

    console.log('The client display name is %s', appointment.client.displayName);
    // prints "The client display name is aarontest'
})
```